# Instant velocity change LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm new to Java and Android. I've recently been trying to create a game for Android using LibGDX. One aspect of this game involves a person moving from one side of the screen to the other (horizontally). This is my code for the person:`

```
public class Man {
    private static final int SP = 10;
    private static final int NSP = -10;
    private Vector3 position;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    private Texture man;

    public Man(int x, int y){
        position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
        velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        man = new Texture ("person.png"); 

    }

    public void update(float dt){
        if (position.x > 2560) {
            velocity.add(NSP, 0, 0);
        }
        else {
            velocity.add(SP, 0, 0);
        }
        velocity.add(SP, 0, 0);
        velocity.scl(dt);
        position.add(velocity.x, 0, 0);
        velocity.scl(1/dt);
    }

    public Texture getTexture() {
        return man;
    }

    public Vector3 getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void dispose(){
        man.dispose();
    }

}
```

I'm still not used to figuring out problems like this. When I run this code, the person goes from one side of the screen (left) and past the other side of the screen (right side, out of view). After a second or two, the person comes back into view (from right side) and goes to the other side of the screen (to left side, staying in view). This process then repeats. Also, when the person starts to move, it takes him a second to get to full speed. I have tried to remove the if else statements and create 2 people with different velocities (one with positive and one with negative) to create the illusion that the man changes velocity instantly(by removing one person and spawning another), but I have not been able to do this.

I would like to know how I could get the person to get to full speed instantly, change velocity instantly at the other side of the screen, and continue this process in a loop. Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walk through your code and think about the logic.

You follow the if-else statement with always adding SP to the velocity. So effectively, you can combine that math with your if-else, resulting in this equivalent:

```
    if (position.x > 2560) {
        velocity.add(0, 0, 0);
    }
    else {
        velocity.add(2 * SP, 0, 0);
    }
    velocity.scl(dt);
    position.add(velocity.x, 0, 0);
    velocity.scl(1/dt);
```

Or more simply:

```
    if (position.x <= 2560) {
        velocity.add(2 * SP, 0, 0);
    }
    velocity.scl(dt);
    position.add(velocity.x, 0, 0);
    velocity.scl(1/dt);
```

So you are always accelerating by 2*SP on every frame, unless you are off screen, in which case your velocity stops increasing, but you're still zooming off to the right, off screen.

If you want to instantaneously change your velocity, you need to set it to a specific value, not add something to it. I would also recommend not scaling and unscaling your vector, because that could start introducing rounding error. Here's how to get your character to ping pong from the left and right sides of the screen.

```
public void update(float dt){
    if (velocity.x == 0) 
        velocity.x = SP; //first frame setup

    //only change the velocity if character is off screen, otherwise leave it alone
    if (position.x > 2560)
        velocity.x = NSP;
    else if (position.x < 0 - texture.getWidth())
        velocity.x = SP;

    position.add(velocity.x * dt, 0, 0);
}
```

Note, I used `texture.getWidth()` as a placeholder for whatever the width of your character is. Really, it is bad practice to load an asset such as a Texture inside your player class. You are mixing up assets with the logic of your game, which is a recipe for code that will be bug-prone and difficult to maintain. It is best to use an asset manager class to load and store all your assets. Your character's draw method can take the asset manager as a parameter and select its asset reference from there. For example:

```
public void draw (SpriteBatch batch, MyAssets assets){
    TextureRegion region = assets.getRegion("man"); //imaginary assets class--implementation up to you
    batch.draw(region, x, y);
}
```